# Why is my app not compliant with Google Play Policies ( Telling me to update to CardinalMobileSDK 5.0.5-rc.1)?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, paypal-android-sdk

I have an app that has dependency :com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.7.3
This dependancy uses a dependancy: org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.7-2

Now, when I upload the app to Google Play, it gives me a warning

> Conside upgrading to version 5.0.5-rc.1

The issue is that the latest version of this dependancy is 2.2.7-5. I added this code:

```
implementation ("com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.7.3") {
        exclude group: "org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle", module: "cardinalmobilesdk"
    }

implementation("org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.7-5")
```

But, it is still asking me to update to 5.0.5-rc.1. Even though this version does not exist.

[image: Image of Warning]

Comment: It's unclear what exactly is being asked here, but I'd start with first updating the "outer" Paypal android-sdk to a newer version (apparently [1.2.1 is already out](https://github.com/paypal/android-checkout-sdk/releases/tag/v1.2.1)). A newer version of that is much more likely to pull in more recent and acceptable depend**e**ncies.

Comment: @JoachimSauer The thing is, I don't want to update paypal to latest version. But even if I did it, the latest version of paypal android sdk uses version 2.2.7-5 of CardinalSDK. Is it possible that it is a mistake from google play side?

Comment: Yes, of course that's possible. But even if it's an error, it's stopping you from publishing your app. My guess is still that there's some context or additional information in the parts that you didn't give that might give an explanation as to what is wrong.

Comment: All I'm saying is that for example 0.8.7 of the Paypal SDK explicitly mentions something about updating cardinal commerce: https://github.com/paypal/android-checkout-sdk/releases/tag/v0.8.7